# How to specify that at least one field is required out of three in total?

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongodb-query, nosql, mongodb-schema

In my MongoDB model, there are 3 fields in total. Any document added to this collection must contain at least 1 of those 3 fields.

How can this be specified in the validation staged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enum validation constraint which collection creation as below:

```js
db.createCollection("jobs", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "status" ],
         properties: {
            status: {
               enum: [ "Done", "Failed", "Initial" ],
               description: "can only be one of the enum values and is required"
            },
         }
      }
   }
})
```

From the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

Mongoose has several inbuilt validators. Strings have enum as one of the validators. So enum creates a validator and checks if the value is given in an array. E.g:

```js
var userSchema = new mongooseSchema({
   status: {
        type: String,
        enum : ['Done','Failed', 'Initial'],
        default: 'Initial'
    },
})
```

---

You can use custom validator to check if we have one of 3 keys in the object

```js
const testSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  field1: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        if (this.field2 == undefined && this.field3 == undefined) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
    },
  },
  field2: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        if (this.field1 == undefined && this.field3 == undefined) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
    },
  },
  field3: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        if (this.field2 == undefined && this.field1 == undefined) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Or did the OP mean there is an inter-dependency between fields/keys, such that at least one must be included in the document?  E.g., a document may contain `{"passportId": 123456789, "driverLicense": "ABC12345", "studentId": "Uni12345"}`, but only one of the fields is required?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes, you are correct

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages update answer please check.

Comment: @Chandan Just to clarify, when the validator function returns `true`, that is equivalent to `required = true`?

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages required is different from validator, required is also a type of validation which check the value is present not undefined or null, validator is to custom validation to make sure the value is what we expect like for example we only want integar type or specific phone format, etc

Comment: @Chandan So what is the reason for the validator function to return `true` or `false` in the above example?

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages if it return false means there is nothing wrong, if it return true means the values are incorrect and it will through error

Comment: @Chandan, well then `this.field2 == undefined && this.field1 == undefined` would not be correct. All 3 fields would need to be `undefined` for it to throw an error.

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages yes you are correct the condition need to updated to include that field3 is present and the other 2 fields to do not have values, I missed that part.